# Google Sheets - Trick to have flexible ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

first time posting here!

I have the following scenario:

1. 1 Google Sheet with information sorted in tables (Master Data)
2. 1 Google Sheet that =Importrange the data from the Master Data Google Sheet.

I need to import one time, or multiple times, some of the rows that are Imported from the Master Data based on the following criteria:
On the Master Data Google Sheet, a column would be present, showing in which Country/Countries the student lives. If the student lives 1 country, import the row once. If it is in 2,3,4... countries, import the same row it 2,3,4... times.

Right now, I am using the following formula:

`=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(Reference!A8,Reference!$A$2&Reference!B6)},"select Col6 where Col10='"&'Advanced Settings'!B5&"'")`

This formula Imports from the Master Data file (`Reference!A8`), a particular tab (`Reference!$A$2)` and a particular range in this tab `Reference!B6`. Finally, it filters the data imported (only the 6th Col of the range, and only if on Col 10 the row has a particular value (`Advanced Settings'!B5`).

Is there a way to Import the name of the student as many times as  countries they live in inside the same Array formula?

Right now, I am just adding more importrange (if there are 3 countries, I will add Importrange three times) with filters, but I would like to make it dynamic for the number of countries, without manual input every time. Also, the number of students imported varies every time so I can't look manually at the number of rows and then add a formula after the last cell of the array formula.

Thanks!
EDIT:
Sample Data and expected result:

1. Sample Data

| Student Name | Gender | Class Level | Home State | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alexandra | Female | 4. Senior | CA | UK, US |
| Andrew | Male | 1. Freshman | SD | UK |
| Anna | Female | 1. Freshman | NC | UK, US |
| Becky | Female | 4. Senior | SD | US |
| Benjamin | Male | 4. Senior | WI | UK |

2. Filter on both Class Level (4. Senior) and Country

| Name | Reason for appearing (explanation for you) |
| --- | --- |
| Alexandra | Appears because Alexandra is Senior, UK |
| Alexandra | Appears because Alexandra is Senior, US |
| Becky | Appears because Becky is Senior, US |
| Benjamin | Appears because Benjamin is Senior, UK |

The expected result here is that Alexandra appears twice as she's Senior and both US and UK.

Comment: Hey, can you give us some sample data, the actual result and the expected result ?

Comment: @Neo I have edited my previous post with a sample table!

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets+first-normal-form

Answer (score 0):

if `Reference!B6` is a range and `IMPORTRANGE` for each country is the same try:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(Reference!A8, Reference!A2&Reference!B6)},
 "select Col6 
  where Col10 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 'Advanced Settings'!B5:B)&"'", )
```

Comment: Hi  @player0  thanks for answering! This helps in the sense that it would capture both countries (US, UK, see below) but what I would like is that it imports the row for as many times as there are countries. The formatting of the country column is very flexible (could be any delimiters)

Answer (score 0):

`IF` C = Senior and `E` is splittable, create a array of corresponding `A`s. Then, `FLATTEN` the array and `REDUCE` to remove all empty items in the array.

##### Sample:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  REDUCE(
    "Senior List",
    FLATTEN(
      IF(
        C2:C6="4. Senior",
        IF(ISTEXT(SPLIT(E2:E6,",")),A2:A6,),
      )
    ),
    LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c="",a,{a;c}))
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks @TheMaster for your answer. How would I use this formula with IMPORTRANGE, hence replacing C2:C6, E2:E6 and A2:A6 with importrange? I keep getting Formula Parse error.

Comment: @MaskedRoach Show your modified formula. Also, it's better to ask follow up questions/new errors in a new post. Formula parse error is a syntax error. You misplaced comma or brackets.